# How To Create Worker in React

Tags: reactjs, worker

I'm trying to create a worker in an app created from create-react-app using react 16.8.6 and yarn 1.16.0. If I use
    `const backgroundWorker = new Worker('../assets/js/myWorker.js');`

I get the console error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

But I know that is the correct path. This works fine in Angular. Is there a good tutorial on how to create a worker in React?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The directory "assets" is the public directory for @angular/cli projects, not create-react-app projects. In create-react-app the equivalent of @angular/cli "assets" is "public" which is described in the create-react-app documentation under [Using the Public Folder](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder#docsNav). Move your "js" directory and the "myWorker.js" file to the public directory and update the creation of the worker to point to that path instead:

```
const backgroundWorker = new Worker('/js/myWorker.js');
```

You can also use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` instead:

```
const backgroundWorker = new Worker(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/js/myWorker.js`);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That does change things. Now i get the same error but it's from /public/js/myWorker.js:1. So it finds the file but it doesn't like the 1st line. The myWorker.js file contains just one line: console.log('from myWorker.js');

Comment: Interesting, I was able to successfully create a worker at this location using the code above from `App.js` on a fresh create-react-app project. Just to make sure, you move the directory/file to the "public" folder that came with the create-react-app project? Also, you are using an absolute and not relative path as my code examples does?

Comment: Yes, that works from App.js. I was originally calling new Worker from a class created in another file and the path generated from VS Code IntelliSense was a relative path (.//.//public/js/myWorker.js) That does not work. If I use: const backgroundWorker = new Worker('js/myWorker.js'); from the class, that works as well. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear it's working. You should consider using `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` just in case your build configuration ever changes and that directory/file is relocated to some kind of subpath for example.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps in order to add your worker files to your `create-react-app` project.

**1. Install these three packages:**

```sh
$ yarn add worker-plugin --dev
$ yarn add comlink
$ yarn add react-app-rewired --dev
```

**2. Override `webpack` config:**

In your project's `root` directory create a `config-overrides.js` file with the following content:

```js
const WorkerPlugin = require("worker-plugin");

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    //do stuff with the webpack config...

    config.plugins = [new WorkerPlugin({ globalObject: "this"}), ...config.plugins]
    return config;
}
```

**3. Replace your `npm` scripts inside `package.json` by:**

```js
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
```

**4. Create two files in order to test your configuration:**

`worker.js`

```js
import * as Comlink from "comlink";

class WorkerWorld {
  sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello! I am doing a heavy task.")
    let numbers = Array(500000).fill(5).map(num => num * 5);
    return numbers;
  }
}

Comlink.expose(WorkerWorld)
```

`use-worker.js`

```js
import * as Comlink from "comlink";

const initWorker = async () => {
    const workerFile = new Worker("./worker", { name: "my-worker", type: "module" });
    const WorkerClass = Comlink.wrap(workerFile)

    const instance = await new WorkerClass();
    const result = await instance.sayHello();
    console.log("Result of my worker's computation: ", result);
}
initWorker()
```

**5. See the output:**

```sh
$ yarn start
```